# Nav-bar not expanding after being collapsed?

Tags: javascript

In this simple expand/collapse navbar I made, the second navbar does not re-expand once it is collapsed, though the first one works fine. Once I collapse the second section, it stays collapsed and will not expand, though the first section continues to work fine, expanding and collapsing Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Here is my code below:

```
<script>
    var CurrentSec;
    var CurrentMenu;
    var CurrentLink;
    function Change(sec, state) {
        CurrentSec = "Sec-"+sec;
        CurrentMenu = "Menu-"+sec;
        CurrentLink = "Link-"+sec;
        if (state == 0) {
            document.getElementById(CurrentSec).src = "http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/collapsed.gif";
            document.getElementById(CurrentMenu).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(CurrentLink).href = "javascript:Change("+sec+", 1)";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(CurrentSec).src = "http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/expanded.gif";
            document.getElementById(CurrentMenu).style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById(CurrentLink).href = "javascript:Change("+sec+", 0)";
        }

    }
</script>
<div class="sdmenu" style="visibility:visible">
    <span class="title" id="community"><img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/clear.gif" class="menuspacer" width="131" height="15" alt="Pirates Community" /><a href="javascript:Change(1, 0)" id="Link-1"><img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/expanded.gif" class="arrow" alt="Close Menu" id="Sec-1"/></a></span>
        <div id="Navbar"><div class="submenu" id="Menu-1">
        <a id="Link-1" >Test1</a>
        <a id="Link-2" >Test2</a>
        <a id="Link-3" >Test3</a>
        <a id="Link-4" >Test4</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(null)"></a>
        <span class="menubottom" id="menubottom">    
            <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/boxbot.gif" alt="-" />
        </span>
     </div>
        <span class="title" id="community">
            <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/clear.gif" class="menuspacer" width="131" height="15" alt="Pirates Community" />
                <a href="javascript:Change(2, 0)" id="Link-2"><img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/expanded.gif" class="arrow" alt="Close Menu" id="Sec-2"/></a>
            </span>
        <div id="Navbar-2">
            <div class="submenu" id="Menu-2">
                <a id="Link-5" >Test5</a>
                <a id="Link-6" >Test6</a>
                <a id="Link-7" >Test7</a>
                <a id="Link-8" >Test8</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(null)"></a>
                <span class="menubottom" id="menubottom">
                    <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/Images/boxbot.gif" alt="-" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are using several ids (navbar, community and Link-*, ...) twice. Each id must be unique. This may be not the only cause, but this should be fixed. What error messages do you get?

Comment: Fixed, still not working. No error message.

Comment: It was still not fixed for every element: `Link-1` is used multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the id for `link-1` more than once; and please check if your open and closing divs are matching.

I changed your function to this:

```
function Change(sec, state) {
    console.log('Change(sec, state)', sec, state);
    var section = document.getElementById("Sec-"+sec);
    var menu = document.getElementById("Menu-"+sec);
    var menulink  = document.getElementById("MenuLink-"+sec); // <-- new MenuLink
    if (state == 0) {
        section.src = "collapsed.gif";
        menu.style.display = "none";
        menulink.href = "javascript:Change("+sec+", 1)";
    }
    else {
        section.src = "expanded.gif";
        menu.style.display = "inline";
        menulink.href = "javascript:Change("+sec+", 0)";
    }
}
```

And the matching html. Instead of `Link-1` i used `MenuLink-1` since `Link-1` was already in use for another element.

```
<span class="title" id="community">
  <img  src="clear.gif" class="menuspacer" width="131" height="15" alt="foo" />
  <a  href="javascript:Change(1, 0)" id="MenuLink-1">
      <img  src="expanded.gif" class="arrow" alt="Close Menu" id="Sec-1"/>
   </a>
</span>
```

You have to do the same for `MenuLink-2`

This is the full html with where the nesting of the open and closing of divs matches:

```
<div class="sdmenu" style="visibility:visible">
    <span class="title" id="community1">
    <img  src="clear.gif" class="menuspacer" width="131" height="15" alt="foo" />
    <a  href="javascript:Change(1, 0)" id="MenuLink-1">
       <img  src="expanded.gif" class="arrow" alt="Close Menu" id="Sec-1"/>
    </a>
    </span>
    <div id="Navbar">
      <div class="submenu" id="Menu-1">
        <a id="Link-1">m1.1</a>
        <a id="Link-2">m1.2</a>
        <a id="Link-3">m1.3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="title" id="community2">
     <img src="clear.gif" class="menuspacer" width="131" height="15" alt="foo" />
     <a href="javascript:Change(2, 0)" id="MenuLink-2">
       <img src="expanded.gif" class="arrow" alt="Close Menu" id="Sec-2"/>
     </a>
    </span>
    <div id="Navbar-2">
        <div class="submenu" id="Menu-2">
            <a id="Link-5">m2.5</a>
            <a id="Link-6">m2.6</a>
            <a id="Link-7">m2.7</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```